# How to add in one .htpasswd file in nginx access to two different domain?

Tags: nginx

How I can add to /etc/nginx/.htpasswd access for two
difference domain for two difference login and password?

Answer (score 1):

If both the domains should have the same logins and passwords, simply add the [`auth_basic_user_file`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html#auth_basic_user_file) directive to both `server{}` blocks. If you require separate lists of users, you would also need separate credential files, as explained in the [answer from Tero Kilkanen](https://serverfault.com/a/1113198/274176).

All you need is also explained in the Nginx Admin Guide: [Restricting Access with HTTP Basic Authentication](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want that credentials for domain A do not work for domain B and vice versa, then you cannot do it with a single `.htpasswd` file.

All the credentials in single `.htpasswd` file are valid for all domains where `auth_basic_user_file` is set to use that file.